# addthis share popup is not working for iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, addthis

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/z2mw3k0a/1/

It works fine on desktop. However, when I use iphone to test Addthis button. The share window will pop up and then hide immediately.

I debugged on safari, and can't figure out the problem,

I just found, for #at4m-menu element, there has a style

```
.at4-show {
    display: block!important;
}
```

When you unchecked this style on safari inspect element tool and check it again, the pop up window will show.

Any help are appreciated.

This problem is fixed by addthis.

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem related with slideInUp animation.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1500px)
    }
    0%,
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0)
    }
}
@keyframes slideInUp {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(1500px)
    }
    0%,
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
}
.slideInUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
    animation-name: slideInUp;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-timing-function: linear;
    
}

.red{
  position: fixed;
  background: #ff0000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="red slideInUp"></div>
```

It works fine in chrome, but not in safari.